# Errro created a soap client

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

Please help me

I'm trying to consume a soap. I use node js and soap

this is the code

```
soap.createClientAsync(url,wsdlOptions).then((client)=>{
                                    client.addHttpHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset=utf-8');
                                    client.addHttpHeader('SOAPAction','http://tempuri.org/ConvertSignDocument');
                                    client.setSOAPAction("http://tempuri.org/ConvertSignDocument");
                                    //client.on("POS")                          
                                    client.POSTAsync(args).then((result) =>{
                                        console.log(result);
                                        console.log(rawResponse);
                                        console.log(soapHeader);
                                        console.log(rawRequest);
                                    }).catch((err)=>{
                                        console.log(err);
                                    });
                                }).catch((err)=>{
                                    console.log(err);
                                });
```

and this is the error

> Blockquote TypeError: client.POSTAsync is not a function
>           at soap.createClientAsync.then (D:\Web\FactElect\route\inicial.js:155:15)
>           at tryCatcher (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>           at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>           at Promise._settlePromise (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>           at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>           at Promise._settlePromises (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
>           at _drainQueueStep (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
>           at _drainQueue (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
>           at Async._drainQueues (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
>           at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>           at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
>           at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
>           at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
>       Envio de factura numero 1 a las Sat Sep 15 2018 07:30:55 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)
>       TypeError: client.POSTAsync is not a function
>           at soap.createClientAsync.then (D:\Web\FactElect\route\inicial.js:155:15)
>           at tryCatcher (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>           at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>           at Promise._settlePromise (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>           at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>           at Promise._settlePromises (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
>           at _drainQueueStep (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
>           at _drainQueue (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
>           at Async._drainQueues (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
>           at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\Web\FactElect\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>           at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
>           at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
>           at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)

I do not understand why it does not work.

thanks.